# Receiving stale data when retrieving all objects in dataset, versus specific objects

Tags: socrata, soda

The data here

http://data.seattle.gov/resource/3neb-8edu.json

for the object with object_id of 6231 has a timestamp field is consistently behind the one that I get when querying for the object directly:

http://data.seattle.gov/resource/3neb-8edu/6231.json

Why is it that I have to directly query for an object to get the latest data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that DOES NOT solve the problem.

What does is adding a ?_= parameter to bust the cache.